# how to autoconnect bluetooth headphone in fedora 25?

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth

New Linux user here. I am migrating from windows to Linux, because I don't like what happening in windows now. I installed fedora this last few days. And everything is going so good so far, except for my bluetooth headphone. I can't make it auto connect after reboot or shutdown.

I already tried many solutions, I found searching but still no luck on solving it. I already reinstalled the OS 5 times, just for this problem.

To use the bluetooth headphone, I just need to do this, connect the bluetooth headphone then navigate to sound settings, then set the audio output device to the bluetooth headphone, then change the profile to A2DP Sink profile. just to use the bluetooth.

My question is, how I can make the bluetooth headphone auto connect, then after connecting it will be automatically selected as the audio output device using the A2DP profile?

I know there is a lot of fedora users, and maybe some of them have a bluetooth headphone, so probably they also face this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I also needed a solution for this, since I'm to lazy to re-configure my sound settings after connecting my bluetooth headphones on my Fedora 26.

In pulse-audio's configuration is a module called "module-switch-on-connect" which will automatically switches to new sinks after connecting them (e.g. a bluetooth device).

So all you have to do is adding the following line to your pulseaudio's default configuration found at `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
# automatically switch to newly-connected devices
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

I've found this in [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Automatically_switch_to_Bluetooth_or_USB_headset).

After this, just restart your computer or restart pulseaudio (as user) with:

```
$> pulseaudio -k
$> pulseaudio --start
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: it doesn't work,  pulse audio wont start if that option is added. It is giving me this error: Module "module-switch-on-connect" should be loaded once at most. Refusing to load.